# Background Video flickers on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm using a Vimeo video as a background video. As soon as the video is loaded, my whole chrome browser flickers.

When I created my homepage a few weeks ago, I didn't have this problem. Maybe it's because of a recent Google Chrome update?

I tried it in Firefox, and everything works fine.

**Warning: If you open the example below, make sure you view it carefully in an extra Google Chrome window, because even the browser controls are blacked, which makes it hard to close it as soon as it starts flickering. You might open task manager additionally.**

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT: For some reason I cannot reproduce it in the snippet. But in codepen:**

https://codepen.io/Insane415/pen/bGByvNB

```css
.video-bg {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.video-bg iframe {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 56.25vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 177.77vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
}
.video-bg > .video-bg-overlay {
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.video-bg .container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}
.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    // 100vh minus header hight min-height: calc(100vh - 77px);
}
.jumbotron h1 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.jumbotron .height-control {
    min-height: 320px;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .jumbotron {
        padding: 12rem 2rem;
        min-height: auto;
    }
    .jumbotron h1 {
        font-size: 2.0rem;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .jumbotron h1 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .jumbotron .height-control {
        min-height: 340px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid video-bg d-flex align-items-end align-items-sm-center">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/253989945?background=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center height-control mb-4 mb-sm-0">
            <div class="col-auto text-left jumbotron-content">
                <div class="inline-block">
                    <h1 class="text-white mb-0">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-left d-inline-block my-4">
                        <li>
                            <i class="la la-check"></i>Lorem Ispsum
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="la la-check"></i>LOrem Ipsum
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="la la-check"></i>Lorem Ipsum
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a href="/Classic-Edition/SW10006" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-5 py-1 mr-4 mb-4 mb-sm-0 btn-block-on-mobile">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                <button id="js-scroll-to-vendor-map" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg px-5 py-1 btn-block-on-mobile">Lorem Ipsum</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /container -->
    <div class="video-bg-overlay"></div><!-- /video-bg-overlay -->
</section><!-- /jumbotron -->
```

Comment: that's weird... Thanks for checking. I started chrome with extensions disabled and it still flickers for me

Comment: Could be a hardware issue. See https://support.streamspot.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000849713-Flashing-video-player-when-using-Chrome.

Comment: @isherwood Yes, that solves the problem. When I turn it off, it works. But I still want people who enabled this setting to be able to view the page normally

Comment: Most of us will. It's a quirk for a few people, and not something you as a web developer should really worry about, IMO. I doubt that there's even a solution you can apply.